# Understanding Typescript syntax

Tags: typescript, currying

I've just started learning typescript recently and I find it incredibly difficult to understand the syntax. The notes I'm provided with weren't sufficient to clear up my understanding so I would like some assistance on it.

In my notes, I have two typescript functions:

```
const operationOnTwoNumbers =
   (f:(x:number, y:number) => number) =>   // I don't understand this line 
       (x:number) =>
           (y:number) =>
               f(x,y)

function operationOnTwoNumbers(f:(x:number, y:number) => number) {
   return function(x:number) {
       return function(y:number) {
          return f(x,y);
       }
   }
}
```

I've added a comment in the code above. Could anyone please explain in simple terms on how I interpret `(f:(x:number,y:number) => number)`?

And then I also have:

```
type BinaryNumberFunc = (x:number, y:number) => number
type CurriedNumberFunc = (x:number) => (y:number) => number

const operationOnTwoNumbers: (f:BinaryNumberFunc) => CurriedNumberFunc 
       = f => x => y => f(x,y)

function operationOnTwoNumbers(f:BinaryNumberFunc):CurriedNumberFunc {
   return function(x) {
       return function(y) {
           return f(x,y)
       }
   }
}
```

I know that both `operationOnTwoNumbers` function are similar in terms of functionality, but how do I interpret those functions and distinguish them?

The way I'm interpreting is:

`operationOnTwoNumbers` is a function that takes in a function as a parameter of `type BinaryNumbeFunc` and `operationOnTwoNumbers` is of `type CurriedNumberFunc` that takes in **`f` as an argument** and returns a **function `x`**, and returns a **function `y`**, and **performs an action** of `f` on **`x` and `y`.**

I'm totally lost trying to understand typescript and would like some help to improve my understanding of the syntax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is 'Currying'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying). This is functional programming knowledge, you can use on JavaScript, TypeScript or any language that support it

Comment: (f:(x:number,y:number) => number) this line mean the TYPE of "f" is a TUPLE like in C# that mean this variable hold a Type which are made up of two further variable which are of number Type